# SQL Server : 2 Stored Procedure 1 for XML & one for data

Tags: sql-server, database, select, stored-procedures, openrowset

I have 2 systems that use the same stored procedure.

The problem is that one system needs data as normal `select` statement inside the stored procedure, while the other needs the data in XML format

I just looking for best practice,

- do I have to create 2 stored procedures so each system read from its own stored procedure?
- or I create one stored procedurefor normal data and the other stored procedure read data from the first one and fill it in temp table using `OPENROWSET`?
- or add a parameter for data output so if I want data i pass 1 if I want xml I pass 2?
- any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think we should have a separate SP for just changing the output to XML format.

Comment: how to it in 1 SP? to add parameter to determine if the output is data or xml?

Comment: Hi, i was referring to your 2nd option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the details of the stored procedure but as a rule of thumb I prefer to add a parameter to determine the output type. In this way you will avoid to maintain two procedures and the risk of going out of sync at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Two Stored Procedures. as using OPENROWSET might have some performance issues.

When you say you need data in XML format, this query will look very different from the query which returns data in rowset and both queries will have a very different execution plan.

So if you decide to embed this non-XML procedure inside a OPENROWSET query and then try to pull XML OUTPUT from that query might result in a very inefficient query plan.

I would say simply create Two Separate procedures and have two separate Execution plans for each procedure which can possibly result in a better performance.

Another Option that comes to my mind is that you can add a Parameter to your Procedure like @XML_OUTPUT and at run time check the value of Parameter and run respective queries, something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_DATA
@Param1     DataType,
@Param2     DataType,
@XML_OUTPUT BIT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (@XML_OUTPUT = 1)
    BEGIN
       SELECT *
       FROM TABLE 
       FOR XML PATH('')..... bla bla
    END
  ELSE 
    BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM TABLE ... bla bla 
    END  
END
```

And at run time if @XML_OUTPUT was set to 1 , the procedure will return XML Data, else it will return non-xml data.

Comment: I also suggest 2 different stored procedures because the stored procedure interfaces are different; there's a big difference between a rows et and XML result.  That said, the advantage of a single proc is easier maintenance.  In either case, I recommend the `FOR XML` clause instead of `OPENROWSET` and temp tables.